# How do you compare multiple strings to find duplicates?

Tags: cobol

Is their a quicker way to compare multiple strings at once and figure out duplicates?

I have 5 course codes that the user will enter. In the case the user enters duplicate course codes the error message should spit out that "duplicate codes detected".

```
       IF((WS-STUCODEL1 > 1)  AND (STUCODE1 = STUCODE2
        OR STUCODE3 OR STUCODE4 OR STUCODE5))
          MOVE 'DUPLICATE CODES DETECTED' TO WS-MSG
          MOVE  'B' TO WS-CURSOR
          GO TO 400-RETURN
       ELSE IF
```

Comment: Use set, but check for uppercase and lowercase string

Comment: How many different course codes are there? Must there be exactly 5 entered, or may some be blank?

Comment: some may be blank, actually running into that issue where if codes 2-5 are left blank it returns the error. this shouldnt happen

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are many course codes available, then

```
       SET NO-DUPLICATE-FOUND TO TRUE
       IF STUCODE5 NOT = SPACES
           IF STUCODE5 = STUCODE1 OR STUCODE2 OR STUCODE3
                   OR STUCODE4
               SET DUPLICATE-FOUND TO TRUE
           END-IF
       END-IF
       IF STUCODE4 NOT = SPACES
           IF STUCODE4 = STUCODE1 OR STUCODE2 OR STUCODE3
               SET DUPLICATE-FOUND TO TRUE
           END-IF
       END-IF
       IF STUCODE3 NOT = SPACES
           IF STUCODE3 = STUCODE1 OR STUCODE2
               SET DUPLICATE-FOUND TO TRUE
           END-IF
       END-IF
       IF STUCODE2 NOT = SPACES
           IF STUCODE2 = STUCODE1
               SET DUPLICATE-FOUND TO TRUE
           END-IF
       END-IF
       IF DUPLICATE-FOUND
           MOVE 'DUPLICATE CODES DETECTED' TO WS-MSG
           MOVE  'B' TO WS-CURSOR
       END-IF
       GO TO 400-RETURN
```

might be reasonably quick.

Note that if any course code is blank, the remaining comparisons to that course code are skipped. This means that `SPACES` in any `STUCODEn` will not cause duplicates.

[Test code to run online](http://tpcg.io/rzZnxo)

Answer (score 3):

If the amount of entries to check is big or may change it is reasonable to use a table to save typing...

One option is to use two PERFORM ([test code online](http://tpcg.io/qimrbR)):

```
   SET NO-DUPLICATE-FOUND TO TRUE
   MOVE 1 TO IND
   PERFORM VARYING IND FROM 1 BY 1 
          UNTIL    IND = NUMBER-OF-STUCODES
      MOVE STUCODE (IND) TO COMPCODE
      IF COMPCODE NOT = SPACES
         ADD 1 TO IND GIVING IND-2
         PERFORM UNTIL IND-2 > NUMBER-OF-STUCODES
            IF COMPCODE = STUCODE (IND-2)
               SET DUPLICATE-FOUND TO TRUE
               EXIT PERFORM
            END-IF
            ADD 1 TO IND-2
         END-PERFORM
         IF DUPLICATE-FOUND 
            MOVE 'DUPLICATE CODES DETECTED' TO WS-MSG
            MOVE  'B' TO WS-CURSOR
            EXIT PERFORM
         END-IF
      END-IF
   END-PERFORM
```

Another option to indexed tables, with use one PERFORM and one SEARCH ([test code online](http://tpcg.io/fTUNuw)):

```
   SET NO-DUPLICATE-FOUND TO TRUE
   PERFORM VARYING EXTRA-IND FROM 1 BY 1  *> not all compilers support VARYING on USAGE INDEX
          UNTIL    EXTRA-IND = NUMBER-OF-STUCODES
      MOVE STUCODE (EXTRA-IND) TO COMPCODE
      IF COMPCODE NOT = SPACES
         SET IND TO EXTRA-IND
         SET IND UP BY 1
         SEARCH STUCODE
            WHEN STUCODE(IND) = COMPCODE
               SET DUPLICATE-FOUND TO TRUE
         END-SEARCH
         IF DUPLICATE-FOUND 
            MOVE 'DUPLICATE CODES DETECTED' TO WS-MSG
            MOVE  'B' TO WS-CURSOR
            EXIT PERFORM
         END-IF
      END-IF
   END-PERFORM
```